# error in rake loading

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am a newbie in rails and trying to run my first application.
Here is what I am doing :
`rails new blog`
Sample Output comes as:

**create  vendor/assets/stylesheets

      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep

      create  vendor/plugins

      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep

         run  bundle install

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

NoMethodError: private method  'open' called for Gem::Package:Class 

An error occurred while installing rake (10.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure  that  "gem install rake -v '10.1.0' succeeds before bundling.**

Running `gem install rake -v '10.1.0'`
Output is:

**Successfully installed rake-10.1.0 

1 gem installed**

But when I run `rake -v` 
Output is :

**rake aborted!

No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

/Users/Lakshmikant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'

/Users/Lakshmikant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in "main"**

Also `rails new blog`  command again shows the same error output.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating rubygems and bundler

```
gem update --system

gem install bundler
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked!. But I had one question -> what is the use of  " run bundle install " and " Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........." as shown in my output above. Also if I am offline , fetching metadata won't work. In this case is this a problem?